# Flutter: Get a PopupMenuButton's PopupMenuItem text in unit tests

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I have a PaginatedDataTable that has a DataCell with a PopupMenuButton. WidgetTester can find each DataCell no problem but I cant seem to reference the PopupMenuButton's items to try to select one.

**How can i get a PopupMenuButton's PopupMenuItem text in unit tests**? Am I using `await tester.pump();` correctly to allow the menu to appear?

Here is how im doing it now:

```
...
expect(find.byIcon(Icons.more_horiz).first, findsOneWidget); // works!

await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.more_horiz).first);
await tester.pump();

var byType = find.text('Quote');
expect(byType, findsOneWidget); // fails!
```

Which fails with

```
zero widgets with text "Quote" (ignoring offstage widgets)...
```

And here is the DataCell markup

```
...
new DataCell(...),
new DataCell(new PopupMenuButton<quickActions>(
      icon: new Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
      onSelected: (quickActions action) {
        _selectContextAction(action);
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<quickActions>>[
            new PopupMenuItem<quickActions>(
              value: quickActions.edit,
              child: new Text('Edit'),
            ),
            new PopupMenuItem<quickActions>(
              value: quickActions.remove,
              child: new Text('Remove'),
            ),
            new PopupMenuItem<quickActions>(
              value: quickActions.reschedule,
              child: new Text('Re-schedule'),
            ),
            new PopupMenuItem<quickActions>(
              value: quickActions.bid,
              child: new Text('Quote'),
            ),
          ],
    ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I found myself in this same problem and I have solved it.

For those having this same problem, I am posting my answer. My test is a little different than yours.

> What is [Pump](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pump.html)
>
> Triggers a frame after duration amount of time.
>
> This makes the framework act as if the application had janked (missed
>   frames) for duration amount of time, and then received a v-sync signal
>   to paint the application.
>
> What is [PumpAndSettle](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html)
>
> Repeatedly calls pump with the given duration
>   until there are no longer any frames scheduled. This will call pump at
>   least once, even if no frames are scheduled when the function is
>   called, to flush any pending microtasks which may themselves schedule
>   a frame.

```
//My Code
//await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.text_fields));
//await tester.pumpAndSettle();

//await tester.tap(find.text(expectedFontSize + ' px'));
//expect(fontSize, expectedFontSize);

//call again if you want to do testing again or something again 
//await tester.pumpAndSettle();

 var mainButton = find.byIcon(Icons.more_horiz); 
 expect(mainButton, findsOneWidget);

 await tester.tap(mainButton);
 await tester.pumpAndSettle();

 var childButton = find.text('Quote');
 expect(childButton , findsOneWidget); //
```

For me the code worked only after calling [PumpAndSettle](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html) Method

Comment: @E.Sun read the yellow quoted part. It basically works as a queue. When you pump and settle it runs at least once to empty and run the tasks in queue.